# How to click on a date within the calendar control in the website using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, calendar

I'm trying to select date from calendar in this website using selenium:

https://www.cbe.org.eg/en/Auctions/Pages/AuctionsEGPTBillsHistorical.aspx

I want to begin from `1st of december 2021` but the date I keep getting is `1st of august 2022`. Any help?

This is the code I use:

```
pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
path="C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe"
driver =webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://www.cbe.org.eg/en/Auctions/Pages/AuctionsEGPTBillsHistorical.aspx")
from_date=driver.find_element("id","ctl00_ctl54_g_1eef16cc_149b_4250_b1db_366c6f7aa7e6_imgFromPopup")
beg_day=driver.find_element("id","ctl00_ctl54_g_1eef16cc_149b_4250_b1db_366c6f7aa7e6_CalendarFromDate_day_0_1")
from_date.click()
beg_day.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to advance to the results of the form (and not testing the functionality of calendar etc), then you can do the following:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Firefox_Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t

firefox_options = Firefox_Options()

firefox_options.add_argument("--width=1280")
firefox_options.add_argument("--height=720")
# firefox_options.headless = True
firefox_options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-A310F Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36 OPR/42.7.2246.114996")

driverService = Service('chromedriver/geckodriver')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driverService, options=firefox_options)

url = 'https://www.cbe.org.eg/en/Auctions/Pages/AuctionsEGPTBillsHistorical.aspx'

browser.get(url) 

start_date = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="date-picker"]')))[0]
start_date_field = start_date.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'input')

end_date = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="date-picker"]')))[1]
end_date_field = end_date.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'input')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].value = "01/08/2022";', start_date_field)
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].value = "08/08/2022";', end_date_field)
```

This will input the dates in those fields, and you can further click on 'View online' and see the results. Setup is firefox/geckodriver on linux, but you just have to import the relevant packages, and observe the part after defining the browser/driver. Selenium documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

This element...

```
driver.find_element("id","ctl00_ctl54_g_1eef16cc_149b_4250_b1db_366c6f7aa7e6_CalendarFromDate_day_0_1")
```

indicates the date *`Monday, August 01, 2022`*

---

### Solution

To click on the date *`Monday, August 01, 2022`* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.cbe.org.eg/en/Auctions/Pages/AuctionsEGPTBillsHistorical.aspx'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id$='imgFromPopup']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table[id$='CalendarFromDate_daysTable'] tbody td > div[id$='CalendarFromDate_day_0_1']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.cbe.org.eg/en/Auctions/Pages/AuctionsEGPTBillsHistorical.aspx'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id, 'imgFromPopup')]"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[contains(@id, 'CalendarFromDate_daysTable')]//tbody//td/div[contains(@id, 'CalendarFromDate_day_0_1')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: FromDate]